# How to allow SQL Server authentication in SQL Server 2017 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, tedious

I'm currently using `node-mssql` that uses `tedious` as it's adapter for connecting to a SQL Server database. I'm trying to get it to connect to my local SQL Server 2017 Express instance.

After figuring out that my Express server wasn't functioning on port 1433, I am now trying to make it so my SQL Server Express accepts SQL Server authentication, but no matter what I do, I can not seem to find a way for it to do so. I can not also get the instance to connect using local machine either.

I have tried using all of the possible options and then attempting to login using my user I created alongside my local machine account that is associated with the database or server.

[image: https://puu.sh/zb1rW/0b02035887.png]

[image: Log on in SQL Server 2017 Express]

[image: Error Message from tedious]

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to enable SQL Server authentication if you didn't select Mixedmode during install.

In Management Studio, right click on server -> Properties -> Security

[image]

> (OP): Okay turns out I needed to enable permission over the table to the SQL user, could you slightly update your answer and I'll accept it, many thanks.

Comment: Express, Developer, Enterprise - what ever - is all the same basic stuff.

Guess you don't have Management Studio installed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: I do not I'll install it and see if it can solve my issues, though I was hoping the configuration manager would suffice as it probably should do for such a simple thing.

Comment: To my experience you can do almost nothing with that tool.
My screenshot is taken from a server running 2016 Express. It's the same in 2017 Developer, and i would be shocked if it isn't the same  in 2008/2012+ :)

Comment: Okay we'll I changed the mode on SMSS as described but I still can't create a pool with tedious using my user called `Liam` any ideas? keeps returning back login failed for user.

Comment: Okay turns out I needed to enable permission over the table to the SQL user, could you slightly update your answer and I'll accept it, many thanks.